# How to reset value of select box to default in react

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code https://codesandbox.io/s/async-http-u9zsg

What I am trying to achieve is to reset the value of the second select box every time I switch movies.

I tried a bunch of different things without any luck. I'm not asking to write me the code, I just want a push in the right direction am I missing something, is my approach completely wrong?

thanks in advance

The code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const query = `{
  allFilms{
    films{
      title 
      characterConnection{
        characters{
          name
          species{
            name
          }
          homeworld{
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    loading: true,
    appliedFilters: {},
    species: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovieData = () => {
      const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ query })
      };
      return fetch(
        "https://swapi-graphql.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/index",
        options
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res =>
          setState({ ...state, data: res.data.allFilms.films, loading: false })
        );
    };
    fetchMovieData();
  }, []);

  if (state.loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  /*work from here */

  const getSpeciesOptions = () => {
    if (state.appliedFilters.movie === undefined) {
      return <option>Select a movie first</option>;
    }
    const currentMovie = state.data.filter(
      movie => movie.title === state.appliedFilters.movie
    );
    const characters = currentMovie[0].characterConnection.characters;
    const speciesList = characters.map(char =>
      char.species === null ? "unknown" : char.species.name
    );
    return [...new Set(speciesList)].map(specie => <option>{specie}</option>);
  };

  const handleFilterChange = e => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      appliedFilters: {
        ...state.appliedFilters,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };

  console.log(state);
  const removeFilters = () => setState({ ...state, appliedFilters: {} });
  const movieOptions = () =>
    state.data.map(movie => <option>{movie.title}</option>);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <select
          name="movie"
          onChange={e =>
            e.target.value !== "default"
              ? handleFilterChange(e)
              : removeFilters()
          }
        >
          <option value="default">Please select movie</option>
          {movieOptions()};
        </select>

        <select name="species">
          <option value="default">Please select a species</option>
          {getSpeciesOptions()}
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to fully control the value of the second select as well. So we add the value of it to the state as well:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  loading: true,
  appliedFilters: {},
  species: [],
  selected: "default"
});
```

Update the second control to read the value from state and also manipulate the state on change:

```
  <select
      value={state.selected}
      name="species"
      onChange={e => {
        setState({ ...state, selected: e.target.value });
      }}
    >
      <option value="default">Please select a species</option>
      {getSpeciesOptions()}
    </select>
```

And finally also manipulate the callback of the first to also reset the value:

```
const handleFilterChange = e => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    appliedFilters: {
      ...state.appliedFilters,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    },
    selected: "default"
  });
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-nash-vtyx7 working example

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create a ref for the second select control.

```
  let ref = React.createRef();
  ...
  <select ref={ref}name="species">
   <option value="default">Please select a species</option>
      {getSpeciesOptions()}
    </select>
  </form>
```

Then in the callback of the first select do this:

```
const handleFilterChange = e => {
  setState(...);
  ref.current.value = 'default';
};
```

With the ref to the elememt you can now manipulate the value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you know ReactJS exactly, but your approach causes you are complicated now. For such cases just keep the `state` of second `select` and after changing the first `select` reset the second one.

```
<select name="species" onChange={handleSpeciesChanges}>
```

I mean to write a state handler for the second select and then in the state handler of first one just reset the second.